# Change width of levelplot in R

Tags: r, plot, levelplot

I have created a levelplot() in R using a data set with 5 rows and 50 columns.

```
rgb.palette <- colorRampPalette(c("green", "red"), space = "Lab")
levelplot(mat, col.regions=rgb.palette, xlab = "Risk Level", ylab = "Zones", main = "Risk  Profile")
```

The result looks like this: [image]

Can someone please advice, how can I expand the plot horizontally and the labels of x-axis to be visible clearly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bu default, `levelplot()` use the isometric aspect so one unit in x equals one unit in y. You can change the default with

```
levelplot(mat, col.regions=rgb.palette, 
    xlab = "Risk Level", ylab = "Zones", main = "Risk Profile", 
    aspect="fill")
```

Comment: Is there any way I can control the size of color plates?

Comment: After you set aspect="fill", just adjust the width of the overall plot. You can also set it to specific values, like `aspect=3` which is the ratio of height to width.

Answer (score 0):

I would use transpose matrix

```
tmat <- t(mat)
levelplot(tmat, col.regions=rgb.palette, xlab = "Risk Level", ylab = "Zones", main = "Risk  Profile")
```